# Lubuntu 20.04 windows too big for the screen

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, qt

I've had a problem with recent installs of Lubuntu 20.04 on laptops with lower resolution screens. Specifically 2 laptops both with screens 1366  x 768 pixels.

One is an Acer with stock Intel graphics and one a Toshiba with Radeon 5430/50/70 graphics, both 1st Gen i5-480M CPU's.

Some of the options/settings windows open up too large for the screen, making it necessary to drag them down and up to access all options. This isn't a problem on the higher definition screens on my desktops which are able to show the entire window.

In an attempt to fix the problem I used the openbox settings to set a 32 pixel margin at the top of the screen to prevent windows opening under the panel ( I prefer my panel at the top).

Upon rebooting, the panel appears across the middle of the screen. Using the panel options to move the panel to the bottom and then back to the top fixes the problem until the next boot, where it re-appears across the centre of the screen again.

I've reset the top margin back to zero to avoid this.

Has anyone else had problems with oversize options/settings windows?
Is there a global means of making these windows smaller?

I have partially fixed some of them by shrinking the font which does make some of the windows slightly shorter.

Edit: Sorry for the delay, I did a stock install on a spare HDD to make sure these problems weren't because of any modifications I'd done to my install. The 1366 x 768 resolution is very common on cheaper laptops. Both the laptops mentioned have 15.5" screens.

The window in question is the Preferences/Terminal settings window in QTerminal. As the pictures show, the bottom of the window is cut off. The other problem mentioned of the panel in the middle of the screen also occurs under certain conditions. I will start another question where I can fully explain how to recreate it.

[image: Terminal settings 1]

[image: Terminal settings 2]

Comment: Can you please be specific with an example of a window/screen/dialog that gives you issue, ideally with a picture.  I QA-test Lubuntu regularly using screens as small as 1024x768 and whilst I do recall issues like you mention for specific dialogs long ago, I can't recall any in a number of cycles (testing currently is on *hirsute* which is soon to release). Details of what you've specifically chosen in Appearance (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html) & Openbox settings may also help (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.11/openbox_settings.html) (even photograph)

Comment: just FYI:  the only netbooks with that resolution (1366x768) I have are x86/i386 so were used in testing up to and including Lubuntu 19.04 (last x86/32-bit ISOs) or 18.04.5 (August-2020) but I still have a hard time seeing how you'd have problems I don't have with 1024x768, but specifics would help.  I have a 1024x768 system running as I write this as I've been testing the *hirsute* wallpapers/greeter graphics & was up to that resolution (last box/resolution I test) and I can't get any dialogs/LXQt windows to appear larger than dispaly; but I'm using LXQt 0.16 being on *hirsute*

Comment: That was a known issue (https://github.com/lxqt/qterminal/issues/574) but I've not yet found the issue on lp (launchpad)... so there is more trail than what I've found so far (I recall testing that & haven't found whatever I did), but I can't re-produce that on *hirsute* (LXQt 0.16) with 1024x768 but I do recall it occurring..  I'll return when I have more, but he "*panel in the middle of the screen*" you'll need to provide a picture & it should be in a separate question on this site I feel (I think that relates to `openbox` but I'll need more details)

Comment: the launchpad bug I was searching for shows *fix released* (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qterminal/+bug/1784198) ...   I know I've answered questions since 2018 though on it; so maybe I'd suggest trying keyboard shortcuts [https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html] to make the window fullscreen (eg. F11)  ... sorry I don't have a *focal* system currently running so I can't test on 20.04 for you (I only have *hirsute* on a 1024x768 system as that's our current focus)

Answer (score 0):

Change in Lxqt appearance - widgets - qt style - Windows.

And tool bar button style - text appears under the icon.
Font - ubuntu light - bold - 10

Now Qterminal preference bottom menus appear.

Else change widgets style to windows in qt preferences, makes qt preference bottom menus appear.

Auto-hide Panel can also be done to view the menu. Right click bottom taskbar (panel) -> configure panel -> tick mark the Auto Hide.

Comment: see the edited answer, change qt style to windows